# How to make KDE remember your opened windows across sessions?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments, session, kwin

This used to work on Kubuntu 14, 13, etc... but since the upgrade to Kubuntu 15.04, after I login only some of my windows re-open automatically. And some of those that do are not in the position I left them. And they are all on the first desktop (I use 4). Even those set to [All desktop].

Also the Konsole reopens with only one tab and it's forgotten the last path.

So, I've checked that:

- [Restore previous session] is set in [System Settings][Startup and shutdown][Desktop session], I even did it manually
- there isn't any funny business in the windows [More actions][Special windows settings][Size and position]

Am I missing some option, or is there a bug somewhere ? The fact that they all end up on the 1st desktop leads me to think of the latter.

Comment: having the same problem with 15.04, it's a real step backwards. konsole used to remember all my open tabs with the correct locations, now it doesn't even start when I log in.

Comment: It seems it is a bug in Plasma:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343518

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, windows get dumped on the same screen because KDE is unable to distinguish them on the basis of "Window Matching" data. This usually happens with multiple instances of the same program, like web browsers or consoles, etc.

I'm looking into this right now and, so far, it looks promising and really tedious.

HTH